# How to map a database view using ActiveRecord?

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Has anybody tried mapping database views in oracle using ActiveRecord? Please can I get some sample code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No code necessary: just use the view name instead of the table in your `[ActiveRecord]` attribute:

```
[ActiveRecord("MyView")]
public class Document {...}
```

Be aware that SchemaExport will treat your view as a table, [here's how to fix](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/mapping-a-view-and-schema-export-workaround.aspx) that.