# mapping view using castle activerecord, exception on primary key

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

Using answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048483/how-to-map-a-database-view-using-activerecord), I'm trying to map my database view. But, it throw exception because I don't define any `PrimaryKey` on the mapping class (the view doesn't have any primary key). Do I need to use `CompositeKey` (this is not recommended, according to castle website) to solve this problem ? Or there is better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/pks.html):

> Regular ActiveRecord types must have a
>   primary key, a key that uniquely
>   indentifies any row in a table. Single
>   surrogate keys are favouvered over
>   composite keys, but both are
>   supported. When having control over
>   the database schema, adding a
>   surrogate primary key to the tables is
>   the recommended way of implementing
>   primary keys.

So add a simple primary key. If you can't, add a composite key.